# C# delaying a thread

Tags: c#, delay

I have three threads: the main thread and two timers. The first timer activates the second one after a period of time and then disables itself.

I use "Thread.Sleep(int)" in order to delay the activation of the second timer. But the whole program pauses when the "Sleep" function is working.

How can I pause a thread without pausing the whole program?

Comment: Show us some code. How are you initialising the timers?

Comment: Yes, show us some code. There are at least three kinds of timers in the RTL. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Timers don't execute your code in new threads. After their interval they raise an event in the Windows Message Queue that the main thread then executes, hence why `Thread.Sleep(int)` is pausing everything.

To fix this, you'll need to actually start your own threads. It's an easy process:

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(() => {
            // Do Something without parameters
        }));
        t.Start();
```

or

```
        Thread t = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart((obj) => {
            // Do Something with parameters
        }));
        Object obj = ...;
        t.Start(obj);
```

There are other parameters you may want to set on a thread before you start it that will affect the rest of your application such as `IsBackground`

Comment: That depends entirely on the type of timer that you use. `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` raises the `Elapsed` event on the UI thread. `System.Timers.Timer` raises it on a pool thread, or on the UI thread if you supply a `SynchronizingObject`. `System.Threading.Timer` always executes its callback on a thread pool thread.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I forgot there were so many timers and assumed `System.Windows.Forms.Timer`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the continuation style programming of the Task Parallel library.

Answer (score 0):

This program will start the first timer after 3 seconds. The first timer will stop after starting the second timer. The second timer will raise events every second after that:

```
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Timer t1 = new Timer();
        t1.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t1_Elapsed);
        t1.AutoReset = false;
        t1.Interval = 5000;
        t1.Start();

        while (true)
        { }
    }

    static void t1_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("t1 timer elapsed");
        Timer t2 = new Timer();
        t2.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(t2_Elapsed);
        t2.AutoReset = true;
        t2.Interval = 1000;
        t2.Start();
    }

    static void t2_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("t2 timer elapsed");
    }
}
```